# SQL Doesnt runs in PHP but does when manually running

Tags: php, mysql, sql

When i manually run the sql query into a SQL client like Navicat, then everything is working.

While i implent it into PHP, something doesn't works.

SQL Query [Example username] :

```
update users
set cardnumber=(select number from cards where used='0' LIMIT 1)
where username='whatever'
```

My PHP Code :

```
<?php
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","password");
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  header('Location: ../error.php');
  }

$sql =  "update users".
        "set cardnumber=(select number from cards where used='0' LIMIT 1)".
        "where username='".($_SESSION['username'])."'";

mysql_select_db("bluecard");
mysql_query($sql,$con);
mysql_close($con);
header('Location: nextpage.php');
?>
```

What went wrong? I can't find it.

[OTHER WORKING FILE]

```
<?php
if(! get_magic_quotes_gpc() )
{
   $firstname = addslashes ($_POST['first_name']);
   $lastname = addslashes ($_POST['last_name']);
   $birthday = addslashes ($_POST['datepicker']);
   $sex = addslashes ($_POST['sex']);
   $region = addslashes ($_POST['region']);
}
else
{
   $firstname = $_POST['first_name'];
   $lastname = $_POST['last_name'];
   $birthday = $_POST['datepicker'];
   $sex = $_POST['sex'];
   $region = $_POST['region'];
}

$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","password");
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  header('Location: ../error.php');
  }


$curruser1  = $_POST['curruser1'];
$sql = "UPDATE users SET firstname='$firstname', lastname='$lastname', birthday='$birthday', sex='$sex', region='$region', order_date = Now() WHERE username='".($_REQUEST['curruser1'])."'";
mysql_SELECT_db("bluecard");
mysql_query($sql,$con);
mysql_close($con);
header('Location: ../-/order/create_account.php');
?>
```

Comment: what doesn't work? any error?

Comment: Try adding a space after `user".`=>`user ".`, or before `"set`=>`" set`, as right now when they are being concated it is being read as `update usersset cardnumber=...`

Comment: This appears to be MySQL so I'm removing the "sql-server" tag.

Comment: if you try to print your query,then you'll know it yourself

Comment: `mysql_query` is an obsolete interface and should not be used in new applications and will be removed in future versions of PHP. A modern replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/). If you're new to PHP, a guide like [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) can help explain best practices.

Comment: Looks like a typographical error if I've ever seen one...

Comment: It is still not working, while my other query does works. Ill add it in the Question/Post.

Comment: @FerozAkbar 1st No i dont try to print it, i try to run the query. 2nd 
if i knew the answer, why would i still ask it?

Comment: yes, before asking something ,you should debug it. If you really tried to echoing the `$sql` then you need not ask this question here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your SQL is starting:  `update usersset cardnumber . . .`.  You need an extra space:

```
$sql =  "update users ".
        "set cardnumber=(select number from cards where used='0' LIMIT 1) ".
        "where username='".($_SESSION['username'])."'";
```

Comment: I never understand why people think they have to use concatenation for things like this. PHP has no problem with newlines in strings, so it can just be written as one long string across multiple lines.

Comment: @Barmar . . . I wonder if it is a legacy from older computer languages where you had to escape the newline to include it in a string.  I have vague recollections of multiple lines all ending with `\` for that reason.

Comment: True, languages vary in this. Javascript doesn't allow unescaped newlines in strings, and many people go back and forth between PHP and JS.